# Different covariance matrices in VAR model

Tags: r, variables, var, covariance

Im using RStudio to analyse a VAR model (using the package `vars`).

```
vardata <- cbind(gap,d_infl,compi2,dln_sharep,i)          #prepare data
vardata <- window(vardata,start=c(1984,2),end=c(2002,12)) #still prepare data  
var1    <- VAR(vardata,p=4,type="const")                  #estimate var
resid   <- residuals(var1)                                #get residuals from model

covres   <- cov(resid)                                    #"manually" compute covmarix
```

That covariance matrix I computed at the very end is different to the one that is already created within the var1 object:

```
summary(var1)$covres
```

Anybody knows why they differ? I replicate a paper and the author is working with the covmatrix created by `cov(resid)`. When I create my Impulse-Response-Functions with `irf`,
R is using the covmatrix within the var1 object.

```
irf1 <- irf(var1,impulse = 'dln_sharep', response = 'i', n.ahead = 72, cumulative = F, ortho = F)
```

Comment: A lot of such questions end up with the answer that one or the other of the procedures is using a scaled version of the data.

Comment: Does someone know how I can adjust the covariance matrix used with irf() ? The package MSBVAR has a function called irf() as well in which I could do that. But it is not working with the "varest" obejct var1 created with the package vars -.-